# Regex expression that keeps upper/lower case characters AND whitespace?

Tags: java, regex, string, whitespace, replaceall

I need to parse some text, I am doing this using a Regex expression within the replaceAll() method. This is the line where I use it:

```
String parsedValue = selectedValue.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
```

This is nearly perfect, it removes the numbers from the string, however it also gets rid of the spaces and I need to keep the spaces? How can I modify it to do this?

For example, "Local Police 101" would become "Local Police".

Comment: `replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}\\p{Blank}]+", "")` or `replaceAll("[^A-Za-z \\t", "")` or `replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\s]+", "")` or `replaceAll("(?i)[^A-Z ", "")` or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're so close!  You just need to add a space to your list of "not", so you end up with `"[^A-Za-z ]"`;

```
String parsedValue = selectedValue.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]", "");
```

Notice the space after the lowercase "z" in your regular expression.

**Edit:**
Looking at your example, you're also wanting to remove the leftover spaces at the beginning and end of the string.  To do this, you will also want to trim the result of replaceAll.  To do this, simply add `.trim()` after replaceAll().  You'll end up with something like this:

```
String parsedValue = selectedValue.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]", "").trim();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I got this from another group I am in:

`String parsedValue = selectedValue.replaceAll("\\d+", "").trim();`

And yes I actually remembered to put the trim() in myself, yay :)

Comment: Also, do you know how to make an expression where it is selective of what numbers to delete? For example if I had "NHS 111 111", I would want to change it to "NHS 111".

Comment: Using `\d+` to remove the digits would allow symbols and everything else to continue staying a part of the string.  If your string is always in the format you're showing, you can remove the last space and set of numbers by doing something like this for your regular expression: `"\\s[0-9]+$"`

Comment: This is not always the case. Sometimes the string will contain only alphabetic characters, and sometimes they may contain numbers as well as alphabetic characters.

Comment: Yes.  That will work if the string only contains alpha characters as well because it just won't replace anything since it will not get a match.  It is though assuming that what you want to remove is always a string of numbers at the very end of the string separated from the rest of the string by a space.  Going by your examples, that should be what you want.

Comment: Another issue - based on what I learnt from this post, I tried using regex to validate a field in a form to ensure that the field doesn't contain A-Z||a-z - however this doesn't work because the form allows me to add a contact with the number field containing numbers: `if (strContactNumber.matches("[A-Za-z]")==true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                              "Please enter a valid number.", 
                              "Invalid Number", 
                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        } ` So basically the above never = true.

Comment: `matches()` compares the whole string.  You need to use a regular expression like `"(.*)?[a-zA-Z](.*)?"` to account for what may or may not come before / after the character found in your string.

Comment: This worked for me in the end: `if (!strContactNumber.matches("[0-9]+"))` Though, I don't know why it works.